# Is dare transitive or intransitive in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs

She doesn’t **dare** to leave the baby alone.

Is **dare** in this sentence transitive or intransitive?

---

*Added by javalatte from comments posted below, because the OP does seem to have hit upon a confusing situation:*

The British English definition in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://%20dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dare.) seems to suggest that it's an intransitive verb, whereas the American English definition in the same place seems to suggest that it's transitive.

The entry in [Merriam-Webster](http://%20merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dare) doesn't seem to shed any light on this at all.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before posting questions. If the research doesn't come up with the answers, they can post a question, quoting details of their research and explainng what specificially they don't understand. In this case, looking at a dictionary definition like this one might provide you with the information that you need: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dare. Note that in this dictionary a verb is marked as I for intransitive and T for transitive.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you. As I am not a native speaker, I also have the "simple" question. Then, could you tell me the `dare` is 'Vi.' or 'Vt.'?

Comment: The transitive form has examples like this: "I dare **you** to...". **you** is the object, which is required for a transitive verb. Is there an object in your sentence- something between **dare** and **to**?

Comment: @JavaLatte  The website you tell to me. `dare` American English: "She wouldn’t dare go out alone there at night."  It is marked as `T`. I don't find an object.

Comment: The sentence in your question has a **to**, but the AmE example does not. They clearly consider "go out alone there at night" as an object. Curiously, the AmE example with a **to** isn't marked as T or I. Well, that's confusing. Meanwhile, Merriam-webster doesn't provide any definitions that have a **to** but don't have a direct object. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dare. Add these links to your question and then ask an AmE native to explain it.

Comment: @JavaLatte  I don't understand your idea. You can change my question to ask AmE native to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster recognizes three uses of the verb "dare" in American English.

**She doesn't dare go** or **she does not dare to go** meaning **she is afraid to go**. MW classifies "dare" in these examples as an auxiliary verb.

It also gives an intransitive usage with the example of **try it if you dare,** meaning **if you are not afraid.**

Finally it gives a transitive use meaning to challenge someone: **we dared him to climb the cliff.**

I am not sure that there is any substantive difference in meaning between the intransitive usage and the auxiliary usage. If I were writing a dictionary, I'd probably lump them together with the meaning "dare = be unafraid, have the courage."

The transitive usage has a different meaning, namely "dare = challenge."